# Modeling Chemical Reactions using a Stochastic Differential Equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, numerical-methods, mathematical-modeling, programming, chemistry

I am working on a simulation project for a biology professor. Per his advice, I need to use a stochastic differential equation to model the kinetic rate of an organism's metabolism.

### Background to the Question:

In a system governed by $N$ biologically catalyzed reactions, here is how I am modeling the reaction rates:

$H_n(t) = X_n(t) \times \prod_{m \in L_n}{C_m}$

Where $H_n$ is the rate of reaction $n$ (in $\mu M$ per day), $C_m$ is the concentration of substrate $m$ (in $\mu M$), and $L_n$ is the set of limiting substrates for reaction $n$. $X_n(t)$ is the kinetic rate coefficient of reaction $n$ at time $t$, which I model with the following [Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process):

$X_n(t + h) = \mu + (X_n(t) - \mu)e^{-h\lambda} + f(t)\sigma \sqrt{1 - e^{-2h\lambda}}$

Where $h$ is the step size, $\mu$ is the mean of the stochastic process, $\lambda$ is the rate of decay, $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of the process, and $f(t)$ is Gaussian noise. In my simulation, $t$ and $h$ are in units of days.

In my code, I generate an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process for all $N$ reactions based on user input. Rather than having the user input values for $\lambda$, $\sigma$, and $\mu$, I have them input values for `TRATE` (typical reaction rate), `TRSTD` (typical relative standard deviation), and `TDECAY` (typical reaction decay).

- `TRATE` can be loosely interpreted as the mean reaction velocity the rate at which a reaction progresses.
- `TDECAY` can be interpreted
  as the rate at which the reaction velocity changes (e.g. the rate of
  reaction acceleration or deceleration).
- `TRSTD` is a value between 0
  and 1 that represents the % deviation from the typical reaction rate.

For reference, here is a short excerpt from my simulation code:

```
import numpy as np

# Typical rate of all reactions
TRATE_MIN = 0.01
TRATE_MAX = 1

# Typical decay rate of all Ornstein-Uhlenbeck processes
TDECAY_MIN = 0.01
TDECAY_MAX = 1

# Typical relative standard deviation
TRSTD = 0.1

def calibrate_ornbeck(N) -> list:
    """ Return Ornstein-Uhlenbeck parameters for N processes. """

    assert TRATE_MIN > 0 and TRATE_MAX > 0, "TRATE_MIN and TRATE_MAX must be > 0."
    assert TRATE_MAX > TRATE_MIN, "TRATE_MAX must be strictly greater than TRATE_MIN."

    means = np.zeros(N)
    sigmas = np.zeros(N)
    decays = np.zeros(N)
    starts = np.zeros(N)

    for n in range(N):

        # Values for TRATE pulled from a uniform distribution
        means[n] = np.random.uniform(TRATE_MIN, TRATE_MAX)

        # Values for sigma are based on mean value
        sigmas[n] = np.random.uniform(TRSTD*means[n], means[n]) 

        # Value for TDECAY pulled from a logarithmic distribution
        decays[n] = abs(pow(10, np.random.uniform(np.log10(TDECAY_MIN), np.log10(TDECAY_MAX))))

        # Starting value is picked close to the mean
        starts[n] = abs(np.random.normal(means[n], sigmas[n]))

    # return mu, sigma, lambda, and starting values (X_n(0))
    return means, sigmas, decays, starts
```

After having the user input values for `TRATE`, `TDECAY`, and `TRSTD` I then generate values for the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck processes based on the parameters returned from `calibrate_ornbeck`. When I execute the simulation, I interpolate between those values using a spline function.

### My Question:

Currently, I have set `TRATE` and `TDECAY` to be some value between 0.01 and 1. However, I want to expand this range of values to account for variability in the kinetic rates. I am not sure what I should set them to though, and I'm having a hard time finding some good papers on how I can set these values. I've found a lot of papers on how OU processes have been used to model [changes in gene expression](https://academic.oup.com/mbe/article/31/1/201/1049642?login=true), but nothing closely resembling the kind of analysis my professor would like me to do.

Would anyone have any advice about how to model chemical reactions using a stochastic process? I feel my mentor has helped me determine the right mathematical framework, but I am lost as to how to reasonably parameterize it.

Comment: I think the keywords are "systems biology" and possibly "reaction diffusion"

Comment: I agree - I'll see if there's a systems biology page on stack exchange.